# Trouble with Couldkit Query and using predicates on field of CKReference

Tags: objective-c, nspredicate, cloudkit, ckquery, ckreference

i have a basic missunderstanding about how CKQuery works.

I have 2 Record types :

1. Friends : containing fields

   - url_of_profil_pic
   - name
   - ...
2. Vote : containing fields

   - date_of_vote
   - target_of_the_vote (Friends CKReference)
   - the_one_who_vote (cloudkit user id)

I am just wandering how I could get the *url_of_profil_pic* when i'm querying on **Vote** table

Basically, wanted smthing like this :

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"the_one_who_vote = %@", recordReference.recordID];
        CKQuery *query = [[CKQuery alloc] initWithRecordType:@"Votes" predicate:predicate];
        query.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"createdAt" ascending:false]];
        CKQueryOperation *operation = [[[CKQueryOperation alloc] initWithQuery:query] autorelease];
        operation.desiredKeys = @[@"target_of_the_vote . url_of_profil_pic"];
        operation.resultsLimit = 10;
        operation.recordFetchedBlock = ^(CKRecord * _Nonnull record)
```

where this line will be the predicate that gives me the URL.

```
operation.desiredKeys = @[@"target_of_the_vote . url_of_profil_pic"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've fetched the record, and that `url_of_profil_pic` is a `CKAsset`, you have to convert the asset URL to a `Data` object that you can save to a file like this:

```
//record is the CKRecord you fetched
if let asset = record["url_of_profil_pic"] as? CKAsset{
  do{
    try yourData = Data(contentsOf: asset.fileURL)
    //Save yourData to disk...
  }catch{
    print("Error saving profile pic from CKAsset")
  }
}
```

Apple recommends saving anything over **1MB** as a `CKAsset` on CloudKit ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckrecord)).

Comment: It works, thanks a lot, as you ( and Apple ) say, i will use CKAsset :)